# To display a string

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have to read a string and display it from a stim.txt file. I can read all other fields but not f_string.If you can advice me how to successfully display f_string. I would really appreciate that

```
stim.txt File extract
0 000aaa 0b0b0b0b " I am here "
```

I am using

```
 initial
  begin
  string f_string; 
  fd = $fopen("stim.txt", "r");
    p=$fgets(line,fd);
  n_items = $sscanf(line, "%h %h %h %s", cmd, addr, data, f_string);
   $display("%h %h %h %s", cmd, addr, data,f_string);
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have quotes that need to be read from your file as well as the string. You will need to read these explicitly, with something like:

```
n_items = $sscanf(line, "%h %h %h %c %s", cmd, addr, data, DUMMY, f_string);
```

where `%c` reads a single character and DUMMY is an 8 bit vector.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. It works but the problem comes when the stim.txt files different lengths of strings.                                                 I used n_items = $sscanf(line, "%h %h %h %c %s %s %s %c", cmd, addr, data, DUMMY, f_string1, f_string2,f_string3,DUMMY2);                     $display(%h %h %h %c %s %s  %s %c", cmd, addr, data, DUMMY, f_string1, f_string2,f_string3,DUMMY2)                                                   I would appreciate if there is a way to deal with different lines having different length of strings.Many thanks.Have a nice weekend